# How to set current day on mat-datepicker

Tags: angular

I want to set automatically the date picker on the current date when the user opens the dialog box and I don't know-how.

Also, I when to make on Code_personnel a validation that validates if Code_personnel = exactly 4 characters so I need to use what type of validation attributes?

my html:

```
        <form [formGroup]="profileForm" class="event-form w-100-p" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
 <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Code personnel*</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="Code_personnel">
                    <mat-error>Code personnel doit composer par 4 chiffres.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>N de tel</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="N_tel">
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
<div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="100">
                    <mat-label>Date de naissance</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker"  formControlName="birthday">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

and the component :

```
 now;
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    Nom_de_famille: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    Prénom: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    email: ['', [Validators.email,Validators.required]],//
    Code_personnel: ['', Validators.required],//I need here aad the 4 charectres validation
    N_tel: [''],
    birthday: [new Date()],//I have tried that
    adresse: [''],
    lieu:[''],
    CIN:['',Validators.required],
    Genre:[''],
    N_permis:[''],
    Département: ['',Validators.required]
  });
ngOnInit() {  this.now  = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
  }
```

Comment: The date must be work, to 4 characters use Validators.minLength and Validators.maxLenht https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators. NOTE: I don't like variable name with accents -better `Departement` than `Département`

Comment: Thanks, Man for validation

Answer (score 0):

In component:

```
startDate = new Date();
```

`Date()` gives you the current time.

In html:

```
<mat-datepicker [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
```

`startDate` property of `mat-datepicker` sets the given month and year in the calender.

Comment: when I tried to add [startAt]="startDate" and set on my ngOnInit     this.startDate = new Date();   it display nothig.